# Merge a list of matrices into a larger matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix

Suppose I have a list of nine, 2 x 2 matrices as defined by:

```
mat_list <- list(matrix(1, 2, 2), matrix(2, 2, 2), matrix(3, 2, 2), 
                 matrix(4, 2, 2), matrix(5, 2, 2), matrix(6, 2, 2), 
                 matrix(7, 2, 2), matrix(8, 2, 2), matrix(9, 2, 2))
```

I would like to merge these matrices into a single 6 x 6 matrix. It would look like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    4    4    7    7
[2,]    1    1    4    4    7    7
[3,]    2    2    5    5    8    8
[4,]    2    2    5    5    8    8
[5,]    3    3    6    6    9    9
[6,]    3    3    6    6    9    9
```

I can accomplish this task using the following code:

```
do.call( cbind, list( do.call( rbind, mat_list[1:3]), 
                      do.call( rbind, mat_list[4:6]),
                      do.call( rbind, mat_list[7:9])) )
```

But how can this be generalized for a very large list of matrices? It would be too tedious to write out the list of `do.call` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe we can do like this

```
do.call(
  cbind,
  lapply(
    split(mat_list, ceiling(seq_along(mat_list) / 3)),
    function(x) do.call(rbind, x)
  )
)
```

which gives

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    4    4    7    7
[2,]    1    1    4    4    7    7
[3,]    2    2    5    5    8    8
[4,]    2    2    5    5    8    8
[5,]    3    3    6    6    9    9
[6,]    3    3    6    6    9    9
```

or

```
> do.call(cbind, Map(function(x) do.call(rbind, x), data.frame(matrix(mat_list, 3, 3))))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    4    4    7    7
[2,]    1    1    4    4    7    7
[3,]    2    2    5    5    8    8
[4,]    2    2    5    5    8    8
[5,]    3    3    6    6    9    9
[6,]    3    3    6    6    9    9
```

Comment: Or a similar option with `seq` `do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(ceiling(length(mat_list) / 3)), function(i) do.call(cbind, mat_list[seq(i, length(mat_list), by = 3)])))`

Comment: Thank you @ThomasIsCoding this works great. Are both of these approaches efficient for a large list of matrices ( >1000)? Or is one faster than the other?

Comment: @akrun Thanks for providing another option!

Comment: @hahsan1 I guess the first one should be faster, but you can test it.